# Nuxt js full static dynamic page, payload undefined

Tags: static, nuxt.js

I'm trying to generate page dynamically. After running nuxt generate the page's are successfully created. But loading the page in (with nuxt start) it says that the title is undefined which I send in the payload while generating.
The payload.js exists for every generated page but it won't work for some reason.

Page result:
[image]

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
    target: 'static',

    generate: {
        routes() {
            const routing = [{url: 'page1', title: 'Page 1'}, {url: 'page2', title: 'Page 2'}, {
                url: 'page3',
                title: 'Page 3'
            }];

            return routing.map(route => {
                return {
                    route: route.url,
                    payload: route,
                };
            });
        }
    }
}
```

pages/_.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>{{payload.title}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        async asyncData({payload}) {
            return {payload: payload}
        }
    }
</script>
```

commands:

```
nuxt generate
nuxt start
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run nuxt generate then nuxt serve in order to test the generated routes.

Comment: I don't know why it wasn't working, at some point it started working and don't know anymore what I changed. For the commands i'll only use nuxt generate and start it with an apache server. PS. I can try to recreate this error for helping purpose