# Payload undefined in Nuxt.js full static generated page

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, payload

I'm building a website with Nuxt.js 2 with static site generation (npm run generate).

I receive the data in my asyncData function and use it to generate the page.

nuxt.config.js

```
 generate: {
    routes(){
      console.log("generate")
      let recettes = axios({
        url: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
        method: "post",
        data: {
          query: queries.generateRecipes(),
        }
      }).then((result) => {
        return result.data.data.recettes.map(recette => {
          console.log(recette)
          return {
            route: `Recette/${recette.slug}/${recette.recipeId}`,
            payload: recette
          }
        })        
      });

      return Promise.all([recettes]).then((values) => {
        console.log(values);
        return values[0];
      });
    },
    fallback: '404.html'
  }
```

Recette\_slug\_id.vue

```
async asyncData({ params, error, payload, $axios, $config: { graphqlEndpoint } }){
        console.log("params",params)
        if (payload){
            console.log("payload",payload.name);
            let recipe = payload;
            if(recipe.compositions){
                recipe.compositions.sort((a,b) => b.quantity - a.quantity);
            }
            return { recipe: recipe, servings:recipe.yield };
        }
        else {
            if(params.id){
                console.log("fetchRecipe", params.id);
                const res = await $axios({
                        url: graphqlEndpoint,
                        method: "post",
                        data: {
                        query: queries.getRecipeDetails(params.id),
                        },
                    })
                if(res.data.data && res.data.data.recettes[0]){
                    let recipe = res.data.data && res.data.data.recettes[0];
                    if(recipe.compositions){
                        recipe.compositions.sort((a,b) => b.quantity - a.quantity);
                    }
                    return { recipe: recipe, servings:recipe.yield};
                }
                else{
                    error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
                }
            }

            error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
        }
    }
```

It is correctly generated and the payload.js file too.
The payload.js is loaded by the browser when the page is loaded.

However, when my object is called client-side it fails because it's undefined. I get the following error: TypeError: this.recipe is undefined

I can't figure out why is undefined. In the created() hook I made a console log of this._data and indeed, my recipe object isn't there

```
created(){
        console.log(this._data);
        console.log(this.dummy);
        console.log(this.recipe);
    }
```

My problem is similar to this one: [Nuxt js full static dynamic page, payload undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737366/nuxt-js-full-static-dynamic-page-payload-undefined) but no solution is provided

Source code is here: https://github.com/nbwns/fristouille

Comment: Where is `this.recipe` located? Cannot see it in the shared code snippet.

Comment: Hi kissu, good question. In fact it's not used client-side at the moment because I removed a call to a function which was using it. 
The error is thrown at page load, as you can see in this page: https://fristouille.netlify.app/recette/nouilles-sautees-au-tofu-et-chou-vert/6194/